# How to fix my login issue?

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, error-handling

I have created a signup form successfully and it is working fine. But my login system is showing error and I am unable to figure it out. Whenever I use to sign in it shows login==empty in URL even when I use exactly same user and password.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conn.php';
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,'$_POST["firstname"]');
      $pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,'$_POST["password"]');
      if ($uid==""||$pwd=="") {
         header("Location:../triallogin.php?login=empty");
            exit();
      } else{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE first='$uid'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $resultcheck=mysqli_num_rows($result);
         if ($resultcheck<1) {
            header("Location:../triallogin.php?login=empty");
            exit();
         } else{
            if ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                //De-hasing of password
                $hashedpassowrd=password_verify($pwd,$row['pwd']);
                if ($hashedpassowrd==false) {
                    header("Location:../triallogin?login=wrongpassword");
                } elseif ($hashedpassowrd==true) {
                    $_SESSION['first']=$row['first'];
                    $_SESSION['last']=$row['last'];
                    header('Location:../triallogin.php?login=success');
                    exit();
                }
            }


         }  
      }
 } else {
    header('Location:../triallogin.php?login=hit');
    exit();
 }
```

Comment: remove `'` from these two lines `$uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,'$_POST["firstname"]');$pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,'$_POST["password"]');`

Comment: It is useful if you tell us ___what error is being shown___ rather than just saying you get an error

Comment: ok I am trying bro

Comment: I will show you what type of error I am getting

Comment: ayush check my answer

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: That ^ I recommend pdo instead of mysqli too https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: http://localhost/comment%20section/triallogin.php?login=empty

Comment: You do realise that `localhost` means basically ___this PC___ So that link will try and find My Webserver and run code that does not exist on my server ?!?!?!?!??!??!

Comment: I am new to PHP and somehow I found, to create a signup and login page so ........................  :(

Answer (score -1):

Three things.

You have put the post vars as a string:

```
$uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,'$_POST["firstname"]');
$pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,'$_POST["password"]');
```

Change that to this:

```
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["firstname"]);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["password"]);
```

Secondly, you are trying to fetch your user login details from the `comments` table? That can't be right.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE first='$uid'";
```

Possibly change that to the `users` table, or whatever you called it.

Finally, your SQL is vulnerable to an SQL Injection attack. The way around that is to to use a prepared statement and bind the parameters.

I recommend using PDO over mysqli, this is probably one of the best articles explaining why, have a read! https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: You have to be careful when answering questions with obvious [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) issues. There are many who will downvote an answer that leaves them as they are and does not attempt to recode using proper [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Actually, delboy1978uk I have created comments table instead of user I know that and I will change it.

Comment: but now I am getting another error it got stuck in login==wrongpassword

Comment: And one of the main culprits is YCS who I believe wrote the articles you are quoting

Comment: what does the code that INSERT's the password look like?

Comment: $pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

Comment: //hasing of password
    $hashed=password_hash($pwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //Insert user into databse 
    $sql="INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `first`, `last`, `email`, `pwd`, `college`) VALUES (NULL,'$first','$last','$email','$hashed','$college');";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    header("Location:../triallogin.php?signup=success");
   exit();

Comment: that __looks__ okay, are you sure you assigned `$pwd` correctly before hashing it?

Comment: $pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

Comment: okay and does your form input have name="password", or just id="password"? Without name, nothing will be posted

Comment: <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="username">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
 </form>

Comment: Everything looks  ok to me